# contact form send email success but no message in my email box - django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have created the below django contact form for the contact page of my website. The problem with the form is that when a user fills and clicks the submit button, it show a success message but the email is not sent. i mean i don't receive message in my box
Can someone please check and tell me where I went wrong.

forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

# contact form
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(required=True )

    contact_email = forms.EmailField(required=True )

    title = forms.CharField(required=True)

    content = forms.CharField(required=True )
```

views.py :

```
def contact(request):
    Contact_Form = ContactForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Contact_Form(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name')
            contact_email = request.POST.get('contact_email')
            contact_content = request.POST.get('content')
            title = request.POST.get('title')

            template = loader.get_template('website_primary_html_pages/contact_form.txt')
            context = {
                'contact_name' : contact_name,
                'contact_email' : contact_email,
                'title' : title,
                'contact_content' : contact_content,

            }

            content = template.render(context)

            email = EmailMessage(
                "Hey , There are new Message from blog",
                content,
                "Creative web" + '',
                ['contact@techpediaa.com'],
                headers = { 'Reply To': contact_email }
            )

            email.send()


            return redirect('Success')
    return render(request, 'website_primary_html_pages/contact_us.html', {'form':Contact_Form })

#end contact form
```

settings.py :

```
#MY EMAIL SETTING
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'contact@techpediaa.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

when user fills all fields it show message send success but i don't received any message why

- i am using namecheap as a hosting

my new settings in settings.py :

```
#MY EMAIL SETTING
EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'contact.techpediaa.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS=False
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'contact@techpediaa.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypass'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Comment: maybe it's in spam?

Comment: no i checked it and no message

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use this for Cpanel.

The processes will be the same for Cpanel as google. You will need to create a app password in the Cpanel

```
EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'your_mail.your_domain_of_Cpanel'
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'app_password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Try it now

If EMAIL_USE_TLS is getting any kind error then edit it False

Comment: thanks for your help again , it say the same error , it show the message was send successfully but no message received and when i check the log it show it's already send and no problem ,, why is that happen

Answer (score 0):

You don't get an email in the inbox, because you're using [django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#console-backend) - as you can see it will just output email in the console. Do you see it there?

[SMTP Backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#smtp-backend) is what you need.

Comment: yes you are right in the console it's appear but no message received ,, i tried @Progam answer and removed django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend line but it show new error it say : `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Comment: did you use `EMAIL_HOST = 'your_mail.your_domain_of_Cpanel' directly? what email host did you pass?

Comment: can you take a look to my question again please because i edit it , you can see my new settings

Comment: do you use docker? can you ping? ```ping contact.techpediaa.com```

Comment: it say : `Ping request could not find host contact.techpediaa.com. Please check the name and try again.`

Comment: EMAIL_HOST is the host of your email sending provider (server which will send emails). You can provide your gmail credentials there for example.

Comment: I mean to specify everything - host, port, user, password

Comment: yeah i understand this point thanks , i will ask my hosting and edit my settings thanks bro